# Google Maps Store Locator Multiple Categories

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a store locator( using Google Maps API v3) where there are 3 checkboxes that filter the markers into Categories. I have got them working separately with if statements but cant figure out how to get them working together. Eg: If I uncheck Bar but its a BottleShop as well( Bottleshop is checked) the marker should still be showing on the map. The markers data is pulled in from an XML file. The three filter categories are Bar, Bottle Shop and Online Retailer. Each marker can belong to more than one filter. Eg: It can be a Bar and Bottle shop.

Example of my XML

```
<marker name="John's Pizzeria" bar="TRUE" bottleshop="TRUE" onlineretailer="FALSE" address="260 W 44th St, New York, NY" lat="40.758072" lng="-73.987740" type=""/>
```

My HTML

```
<div id="location"></div>
<div id="map" class="map" style="height:400px; width:600px;"></div>
<input id="addressInput" value="Enter location" />
<input id="radiusSelect" value="25" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="Search"/>
<form action="#">
    Bar: <input type="checkbox" id="bar" onclick="boxclick(this,'bar')" checked/>
    Bottle Shop: <input type="checkbox" id="bottleshop" onclick="boxclick(this,'bottleshop')" checked/>
    Online Stockist: <input type="checkbox" id="onlineretailer" onclick="boxclick(this,'onlineretailer')" checked/>
</form>  
<select id="locationSelect" class="span12"></select>
```

My JavaScript

```
var map  = null;
var markers = []; 
var infoWindow;
var True = "TRUE";
var catBar = [];

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Load Google Maps
    load();
    //When user clicks search, fire the search locations function
    $('#search').click(function() {
      searchLocations();
    });
});  

//On page load Create a google map in #map
//Set default cordinates & Map style to roadmap
function load() {

  var location = "Showing default location for map.";
  var locationSelect;
  //Set default Lat Long for when map loads
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787,-79.359741);
  // If users location is found then overwrite latlng variable and use this location
  if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
    zoom = 13;
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude, google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude);
    location = "Showing IP-based location: <b>" + getFormattedLocation() + "</b>";
    address = getFormattedLocation();
    // Add users location to search input and load local stores
    document.getElementById('addressInput').value=address;
  }
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions); 
      document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = location;
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });
  locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (markerNum != "none") {
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    }
  };
  searchLocations();
}
//Format the location
function getFormattedLocation() {
  if (google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code == "US" &&
    google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region) {
    return google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city + ", " 
      + google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      return  google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city + ", "
      + google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
  }
}
//Search for LAT/LNG of a place using its address using Google Maps Geocoder
function searchLocations() {
  var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //console.log('search worked');
    //console.log(results);
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert(address + ' not found');
    }
  });
}

//Clears Previous location, in info box
function clearLocations() {
 infoWindow.close();
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   markers[i].setMap(null);
 }
 markers.length = 0;
 locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
 var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.value = "none";
 option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
 locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}

//Look for locations near by and loop through all data getting lat & lng of each marker
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
  clearLocations();
  searchLoc = center;
  var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
  //console.log(radius);
  var searchUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/starward/wp-content/themes/starward/map_request.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
  var xml = parseXml(data);
  var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // alert(markerNodes.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
    var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
    var barValue = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("bar");
    var bottleshopValue = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("bottleshop");
    var onlineRetailerValue = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("onlineretailer");
    var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
    var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
    var zoom = 13; //Infowindow Zoom level
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
    parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    if (!distance) distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng, searchLoc);
    if (!address) address = latlng.toUrlValue(6);
    if (!name) name = "marker "+i;
    createOption(name, distance, i);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    //Make sure paremeters are in correct order or values will be mixed up
    createMarker(latlng, name, address ,zoom, barValue, bottleshopValue, onlineRetailerValue);
  }
  //map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setZoom(13);
  map.setCenter(center);
  locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
   };
 });
}

//Creates marker on the map
//Adds event for user when they click address info pops up
function createMarker(latlng, name, address, zoom, barValue, bottleshopValue, onlineRetailerValue) {
  // add the zoom links
  var html =  "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address 
  html += '<br><a  href="javascript: map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+'));map.setZoom('+zoom+');">Zoom To</a>';
  html += ' <a  href="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+')); map.setZoom(parseInt(map.getZoom())+1);">[+]</a>';
  html += ' <a  href="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+')); map.setZoom(parseInt(map.getZoom())-1);">[-]</a>';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  marker.barValue = barValue;
  marker.bottleshopValue = bottleshopValue;
  marker.onlineRetailerValue = onlineRetailerValue;
  marker.MyZoom = zoom;
  markers.push(marker);
}

function show(category) {
  //console.log(category);
  for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].barValue === 'TRUE' && "bar" === category) {
      markers[i].setVisible(true);
    } else if (markers[i].bottleshopValue === 'TRUE' && "bottleshop" === category) {
      markers[i].setVisible(true);
    } else if (markers[i].onlineRetailerValue === 'TRUE' && "onlineretailer" === category) {
      markers[i].setVisible(true);
    } else {

    }
  }
}

 //Hides markers not in current ticked category 
function hide(category) {
  //console.log('hide function');
  for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    //console.log(markers[i].barValue);
    if (markers[i].barValue === "TRUE" && "bar" === category  ) {
      //console.log('hiding markers');
      markers[i].setVisible(false); 
    } else if (markers[i].bottleshopValue === "TRUE" && "bottleshop" === category ) {
       markers[i].setVisible(false); 
    } else if (markers[i].onlineRetailerValue === 'TRUE' && "onlineretailer" === category) {
      markers[i].setVisible(false);
    } else {

    }
  }
}

// == a checkbox has been clicked ==
function boxclick(box,category) {
  if (box.checked) {
    show(category);
  } else {
    hide(category);
  }
    // == rebuild the side bar
    // makeSidebar();
}
function createOption(name, distance, num) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = num;
  option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}
//Look up XML sheet to get data
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
  new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone gave me this answer but there answer has disappeared. There code ended up working

```
function boxclick() {
    //create an array of the checked checkbox-IDs
    var c = j.grep(['onlineretailer','bottleshop','bar'],
        function(i) {
            return (j('#'+i.toLowerCase()+':checked').length);
            //console.log(i); i holds each value in the array in lowercase form
    });
    //console.log(c); // C holds all the checkbox values in an array

    //iterate over the markers and set their visibility
    //to true when at least 1 of the checkbox-values matches
    //otherwise to false
    j.each(markers,function(i,m) {
        this.setVisible(j.grep(c,function(v) {
            console.log(c,v,m); // c = checkboxes checked, v = value , m = marker
            return (m[v+'Value']=='TRUE')
        }).length>0);
    });  
}
```

Comment: Helpful to add this code in to. So that you make sure info windows are closed incase the marker disappears -infoWindow.close();

Comment: Someone gave you this answer(and it was exactly the same code), and you commented his answer with "but not quite working" .

Comment: Yes then I realised his script was correct and it was something else I had done since that had broken it. Went back to upvote his answer but it was deleted. So I posted the answer again